# Average of sum of date difference.. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to find the average time it takes for an employee to get a salary raise from the time of hiring.

I've tried a few things, but I'm not getting it right.

Here's what my database looks like: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(datediff(hire_date, min((SELECT from_date FROM salaries
                                        WHERE from_date > hire_date AND
                                        (SELECT salary FROM salaries
                                         WHERE from_date = hire_date) <
                                        (SELECT salary FROM salaries 
                                         WHERE from_date > hire_date))))))
FROM employees;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, logically this should be correct (maybe not), I'm probably just messing up with syntax some how..

Thanks!

Comment: Time to read about joins I suspect

Comment: Actually, contrary to the answer provided below, I think the problem is insoluble. Because salaries.emp_no is a PRIMARY KEY, we can only know the hire date, and the date of the most recent salary increase. With this information, we can only discern the average time between hiring and the most recent salary increase, which is not what you wish to know (as it's a meaningless statistic). If the PK was instead formed on (emp_no,from_date), then the problem would be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach this to make things that you are trying to achieve explicit:

```
   SELECT AVG(datediff(e.hire_date, second_salary.from_date))
   FROM 
     employees e INNER JOIN 
     salaries first_salary ON e.emp_no = first_salary.emp_no AND
                              first_salary.from_date = e.hire_date INNER JOIN
     salaries second_salary ON e.emp_no = second_salary.emp_no AND
               second_salary.from_date > e.hire_date AND
               second_salary.salary > frist_salary.salary AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM salaries s 
                WHERE s.emp_no = e.emp_no AND 
                      s.from_date > e.hire_date AND
                      s.from_date < second_salary.from_date AND
                      s.salary > first_salary.salary)

    ;
```

This type of analysis requires a lot of profiling and data quality validation though. I would not trust date conditions too much for this type of data.

Comment: There's quite a lot of query here.

Comment: @Strawberry you are welcome to reduce. this is what I believe is needed.

Comment: i might in the morning. Bit late for me now.

Comment: @Bulat Thanks for the help, I've tested it an it works. I'm not sure if the data output is correct but that's okay. I started SQL a couple of weeks ago and the Professor is already giving us practice problems such as the one above. From your experience is this too difficult for a SQL noob to come up with? It's the person's first time teaching a college course, and the whole class is having issues. It's like she gives us problems to solve that she herself hasn't actually worked out. I'd really like some input from an experienced SQL person.

Comment: @Bulat ^ Please refer to above comment, hahah thanks

Comment: The answers in SQL are easy once you get intuition for it, e.g. learn to think in set logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy query, but probably it is in the course for you to try to find it by yourself and, during that process, learn a lot of SQL.

In a real system development situation, if SQL gets too heavy or complex sometimes it is easier for the programmer to do more queries, use a stored procedure or solve it in the programming language.

But, as a help, I believe this would make the trick:

```
select avg(md) from (
    select emp_no, min(days) as md from 
        (select  s1.emp_no as emp_no, 
                 s1.from_date as start, 
                 datediff(s2.from_date,s1.from_date) as days 
                 from employees e inner join salaries s1 on                   
                 e.emp_no=s1.emp_no 
                 inner join salaries s2 on s1.emp_no=s2.emp_no 
                 where 
                 s2.from_date <> s1.from_date and
                 s1.from_date < s2.from_date and
                 s1.from_date = e.hire_date
         ) t ) tt group by emp_no
```

The idea is first make an expensive JOIN to find all differences of dates (from s2s2 - from of s1) but only when date_from is equal hire_date and the dates are not equal. (diff=0).

The second internal select gets the minimum value for each employee, this is for sure the first promotion.

The outer select makes the average.

Comment: @ Xexeo Hey, just read this! Thanks for the insight, practice makes perfect.